# Socket.DuplicateAndClose() And recreate socket by SocketInformation

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming, winsock

some background, trying to make an simple app that can create P2P connection between registered peers in Tracker, kinda trying to make p2p architect from scratch XD
( please any help or resource *O*_**O** )

the **trackerServer** just hold the connected client socket information in a list and query it for request

```
namespace PeerTrackerServer
{
    public class PeerSockets
    {
        public string PeerName { get; set; }
        public byte[] SocketInformation { get; set; }
    }

    public class NetworkCommandMessage
    {
        public NetworkCommandMessage(byte[] command)
        {
            var strData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(command);
            var arrSplited = strData.Split(':');
            this.Command = arrSplited[0].ToLower().Trim();
            this.Data = arrSplited[1].Replace("\0","").ToLower().Trim();
        }
        public string Command { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static List<PeerSockets> _Peers;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _Peers = new List<PeerSockets>();

            var srvSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1313);
            srvSocket.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var client = srvSocket.AcceptSocket();
                var tsk = new Task(new Action(() => { PeerHandler(client); }));
                tsk.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void PeerHandler(Socket client)
        {
            var commandBuff = new byte[128];
            client.Receive(commandBuff);
            var netMSG = new NetworkCommandMessage(commandBuff);

            switch (netMSG.Command)
            {
                case "register":
                    var duplicatedSocket = client.DuplicateAndClose(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                    _Peers.Add(new PeerSockets
                    {
                        PeerName = netMSG.Data,
                        SocketInformation = duplicatedSocket.ProtocolInformation
                    });
                    break;
                case "connect":
                    var requestedUser = _Peers.Where(c => c.PeerName == netMSG.Data).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (requestedUser != null)
                    {
                        client.Send(requestedUser.SocketInformation);
                        client.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var msg = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Requested User Not Found !");
                        client.Send(msg);
                        client.Close();
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Client_1** register itself to Tracker Server and Server Duplicate its socket And keep it alive ( for how long i don't know! ^_^ )

```
namespace Client_1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Socket _Socket;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Register To Tracker Server
            var tsk = new Task(new Action(() => { RegisterMe(); }));
            tsk.Start();
            tsk.Wait();

            //Start Receiving Data
            var buff = new byte[4096];
            var ns = new NetworkStream(_Socket, true);
            var readCount = 0;

            while ((readCount = ns.Read(buff,0,buff.Length))>0)
            {
                var strData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff, 0, readCount);
                Console.Write(strData);
            }
        }

        public static void RegisterMe()
        {
            var registerBuffer = new byte[128];

            var tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1313);
            var registerCommand = "register:Client1";
            var cmdData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registerCommand);
            Array.Copy(cmdData, registerBuffer, cmdData.Length);

            var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            ns.Write(registerBuffer, 0, registerBuffer.Length);
            ns.Flush();

            _Socket = tcpClient.Client;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **Client_2** try to Receive the duplicated Client_1 socket information and recreate socket ,the client_1 currently waiting for receive data

```
namespace Client_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buffConnect = new byte[128];
            var cmdConnect = "connect:Client1";
            var cmdData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cmdConnect);
            Array.Copy(cmdData, buffConnect, cmdData.Length);

            //send Connect Command
            var tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1313);
            var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            ns.Write(buffConnect, 0, buffConnect.Length);
            ns.Flush();

            //Wait For ProtocolSocketInformation
            var buff = new byte[32*4096];
            var readBytes = 0;
            readBytes = ns.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);

            var sockProtocolInfo = new byte[readBytes];
            Array.Copy(buff,sockProtocolInfo,readBytes);

            //Create New Socket
            var peerSocketInfo = new SocketInformation();
            peerSocketInfo.ProtocolInformation = sockProtocolInfo;
            peerSocketInfo.Options = SocketInformationOptions.Connected;

            /*
            * HERE IS THE ERROR ArgumentException : "The specified value for the socket information is invalid"
            */
            var peerSocket = new Socket(peerSocketInfo);


            //Send Message To Peer Client
            var msg = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n\r\nYoo there ! Im From Client 2!\r\n");
            var peerNS = new NetworkStream(peerSocket);
            peerNS.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            peerNS.Flush();
            peerNS.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe why you are duplicating sockets? I suspect that it does not do what you think it does...

Comment: some way to Send the accepted socket object in the TrackerServer to peer2 that can figure out witch ip & port (NAT info) peer1 is currently listening take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/12/26/507461.aspx

Comment: This will only work on the local machine. Just making sure you are aware of that. You can't transfer sockets over the network. Maybe you should just send IP and port number. Also, in your Read-calls you assume that an entire buffer will be read - this is not guaranteed. Read can return as little as one byte. TCP has no message boundaries.

Comment: thanks for replay :D ,,, any idea how to implement peer to peer ?

Comment: Send IP and port number so that the other side can initiate a connection. Also note, that TCP connections are bidirectional. Once you are connected, both sides can send messages. Please also read a TCP tutorial and inform yourself about common pitfalls (https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=socket+pitfalls).